# Resizing an image in python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have an image of size (288, 352). I want to resize it to (160, 240).
I tried the following code:

```
im = imread('abc.png')
img = im.resize((160, 240), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

But it gives an error `TypeError: an integer is required`
Please tell me the best way to do it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`matplotlib.pyplot.imread` (or `scipy.ndimage.imread`) returns a NumPy array, not a PIL Image.

Instead try:

```
In [25]: import Image
In [26]: img = Image.open(FILENAME)
In [32]: img.size
Out[32]: (250, 250)

In [27]: img = img.resize((160, 240), Image.ANTIALIAS)

In [28]: img.size
Out[28]: (160, 240)
```